# C programming ncurses input validate

Tags: c, validation, input, character, ncurses

I am doing a small project using ncurses and writing in C. Two problems come across me which are about validate input. 
For example, case 1: I want to validate that input is a specified specific character e.g: a or b or c.

```
char choice;
printw("a. New name\n");
printw("b. Edit name\n");
printw("c. Exit\n");

scanw("%c", &choice);

if (choice == 'a')
    //Do something
else if(choice =='b') {
   //Do something
}
else if(choice == 'c') {
    exit(0);
}
```

Case 2: I want to validate input only within a range of integer numbers e.g: 1 to 5.

```
int player_number
printw("How many players ? (1 - 5): ");
scanw("%i", &player_number);
```

It's ironical I can find a solution to both of these 2 problem out of ncurses context. Plus, how can I quit my program with keystroke like 'q' whenever it prompts user input.
Thank you

Comment: No code to show ? No output ?

Comment: just prepend `endwin();` before `exit(0);` in your code for `'c'`  char, so you wont get your output screen blurred.  Or do it with an `atexit(3)` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    char choice = 0;
    int player_number = -1;

    initscr ( );
    do {
        mvprintw ( 1, 1,"a. New name");
        mvprintw ( 2, 1,"b. Input number");
        mvprintw ( 3, 1,"c. Exit");
        mvprintw ( 4, 1," ");
        if (( scanw("%c", &choice)) == 1) {//scanw succeeded
            if ( ! ( choice == 'a' || choice == 'b' || choice == 'c')) {
                mvprintw ( 5, 1,"invalid input, should be a, b or c");
            }
            else {
                mvprintw ( 5, 1,"                                  ");
            }
        }
    } while ( ! ( choice == 'c' || choice == 'b'));
    mvprintw ( 5, 1,"                                  ");
    if ( choice == 'b') {
        do {
            mvprintw ( 7, 1,"Enter number 0-9");
            mvprintw ( 8, 1," ");
            if (( scanw("%d", &player_number)) == 1) {//scanw succeeded
                if ( player_number < 0 || player_number > 9) {
                    mvprintw ( 9, 1,"invalid input, should be 0-9");
                }
            }
            else {//scanw failed
                mvprintw ( 9, 1,"invalid input, should be 0-9");
            }
        } while ( player_number < 0 || player_number > 9);

    }
    endwin ( );
    return 0;
}
```

Using a char array to contain input and `getnstr()` to read the input, it is possible to detect an input of `q` to quit the program. For numeric input, `strtol()` is used to convert the array to an int.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    char choice = 0;
    char instr[128] = {0};
    int player_number = -1;

    initscr ( );
    do {
        mvprintw ( 1, 1,"a. New name");
        mvprintw ( 2, 1,"b. Input number");
        mvprintw ( 3, 1,"c. Exit");
        mvprintw ( 4, 1," ");
        if (( getnstr( instr, 1)) != ERR) {//succeeded
            choice = instr[0];
            if ( ! ( choice == 'a' || choice == 'b' || choice == 'c')) {
                mvprintw ( 5, 1,"invalid input, should be a, b or c");
                if ( choice == 'q') {//quit when q is entered
                    endwin ( );
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                mvprintw ( 5, 1,"                                  ");
            }
        }
    } while ( ! ( choice == 'c' || choice == 'b'));
    mvprintw ( 5, 1,"                                  ");
    if ( choice == 'b') {
        do {
            mvprintw ( 7, 1,"Enter number 0-9");
            mvprintw ( 8, 1," ");
            if (( getnstr( instr, sizeof ( instr))) != ERR) {//succeeded
                if ( instr[0] == 'q' && instr[1] == '\0') {//quit when q is entered
                    endwin ( );
                    return 0;
                }
                player_number = strtol ( instr, NULL, 10);
                if ( player_number < 0 || player_number > 9) {
                    mvprintw ( 9, 1,"invalid input, should be 0-9");
                }
            }
            else {//failed
                mvprintw ( 9, 1,"invalid input, should be 0-9");
            }
        } while ( player_number < 0 || player_number > 9);
    }
    endwin ( );
    return 0;
}
```